# i3 throttled at 500Mhz when battery under 30%

Tags: 15.10, power-management, battery, intel-cpu

I have the following problem. As soon as the battery drops below 30%, the CPU is being throttled to 500Mhz. As soon as I plug in the power adapter, it goes back to normal. The laptop is a Lenovo U41-70, I am running Ubuntu 15.10 x64, the CPU is an Intel i3-5020U.

I am not sure if this is helpful, but while it's on battery and below 30%, `lscpu` (same values from `cat /proc/cpuinfo`) still gives out:

```
CPU MHz:               499.984
CPU max MHz:           2200,0000
CPU min MHz:           500,0000
```

When it's plugged in, CPU MHz immediately jumps up to 2195.015Mhz when there is load on the CPU, which is fine of course.

What could cause this problem? I don't have Windows installed so I don't know if the problem exists there as well.

Comment: have you dug through your BIOS settings?

Comment: Incidentally, I had an issue like this years ago when my Dell laptop didn't recognize my Dell power cable as being from Dell! It locked my laptop at low-cpu speeds until I found another Dell power cable. Since yours is "only under 30% battery" it won't be your issue, but it's an example of the system taking over at the BIOS level and knee-capping you.

Comment: lscpu and /proc/cpuinfo are not appropriate tools to monitor your CPU.  Checkout your CPU with the proper tool i.e. powertop --> Frequency stats

Comment: Thank you! Indeed, lscpu does not seem very accurate, I put the notebook under full load from about 29% to 5% battery, and powertop says 90% at 600MHz and 10% at 500. It looks like everything is alright in the BIOS.

Comment: As I could not get this problem resolved I will install Windows and see how that goes. This bug/feature/problem makes Ubuntu unusable for me.

Comment: Under your problem conditions what do you get for `sudo rdmsr -a 0x19a`? You will need msr-tools installed and `sudo modprobe msr` first.

Comment: Have you tried updating the BIOS?  This could be a BIOS related issue.  Many BIOS update packages contain a DOS-based flasher that can be used with a FreeDOS USB.  If no DOS-based solution is available, you could use [F4UBCD](https://falconfour.wordpress.com/2013/08/08/falconfours-ultimate-boot-cd-v4-61-patch/).

Answer (score 1):

## Edit a file

You can always change your clock speed by controlling Intel-pstate.

Intel-pstate can be controlled by changing files in `/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate` (Change as root i.e. using `sudo`)

## Use a bash script

You can use this bash file, which I created for my own use. Note that I don't think i3 supports turbo boost.

1. Download the file [from google drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4etFrzyEA01Si0yRFRxLTFtVTA/view?usp=sharing)
2. Run `sudo chmod 775 set_cpu_pstate`
3. Execute with `sudo ./set_cpu_pstate`
4. Set MAX power to `100`
5. Set MIN power to `100` to force high performance all the time
6. Enter `1` to activate TurboBoost or `0` to deactivate it

## CPU Frequency

You can use i7z for current CPU frequency.

```
sudo apt-get install i7z
sudo i7z
```

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a bug in the Lenovo BIOS that initializes the thermal zone limit to passive 0 (/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/trip_point_2_temp), thus tripping overheat policies. If you rmmod then modprobe thermal, it should set you back to normal if you're having this problem on a Lenovo laptop.

Comment: That Lenovo BIOS problem manifests itself as a reduction in CPU frequency for each suspend / resume cycle. Myself, I do not believe it to be the same as this problem. I suspect, but have no proof that this is a Clock Modulation when battery low issue. see [also](http://askubuntu.com/questions/745087/cpu-clock-slower-after-each-resume-from-sleep).